# Por que no me deja cambiar el numero

Tags: javascript, funciones, formato, autonumeric

Quiero poner un numero diferente pero me parte los resultados de abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando esta funcion para el formato.

```
function dar_formato(num){

    var cadena = ""; var aux;
    
    var cont = 1,m,k;
    
    if(num<0) aux=1; else aux=0;
    
    num=num.toString();
    
    for(m=num.length-1; m>=0; m--){
    
     cadena = num.charAt(m) + cadena;
    
     if(cont%3 == 0 && m >aux)  cadena = "," + cadena; else cadena = cadena;
    
     if(cont== 3) cont = 1; else cont++;
    
    }
    
    
    
    return cadena;
}
```

Comment: Agrega tu HTML, variables, todo...

Comment: El problema es cuando te vienen numeros con puntos o comas. para que funcione tu método tiene que ir un numero sin estos caracteres

Comment: Y que puedo hacer para solucionarlo.

Comment: @JoseAlbertoSimon pues como te indican arriba, tenemos que ver tu HTML para que tu código sea reproducible y poder ayudarte con más facilidad.

Comment: Hola @JoseAlbertoSimon, si Suso está en lo cierto, deberías implementar un método para **"desformatear"** los datos que le pides al html.